# Changing color inside of the legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a question regarding changing the color of a specific part of the legend in ggplot;[image]

I marked it in the picture of the plot, because I don't really know what it is called, it's the area around the color code on the legend, I'd like it to be of the same color as the background of the legend. Is that even possible?..

Here's my complete code:

```
movies <- read.csv(file.choose())

setwd("/Users/marimatiss/Desktop/R_course_Kirill/5. Advanced visualization")

colnames(movies) <- c("Film", "Genre", "CriticRating", 
     "AudienceRating", "BudgetMillions", "Year")



ggplot(movies) + 
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=AudienceRating, y=CriticRating, 
  color=Year, fill=Year, size=BudgetMillions), alpha=0.6, shape=23) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#8A8635", "#AE431E", "#630000", 
     "#D8B6A4", "#105652")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="#FBF3E4"), 
   plot.background = element_rect(fill="#FBF3E4"), 
    legend.background = element_rect(fill="#FBF3E4"), 
     panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(title="Movie ratings", subtitle="by year")
```

Comment: You can add `legend.key = element_rect(fill="#FBF3E4")` to your theme to match the background color.

Comment: @Seth I _just_ found that (after iteratively trying all found in `names(theme_classic())`). You should post that as an answer.

Comment: (I wonder if `legend.key.background` would be a more appropriate name ...)

Comment: the legend.key absolutely worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The background of the keys can be changed directly through
`theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill="#FBF3E4"))`

The description in the [reference documentation with the full list of components](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) is useful here, but I agree you'd probably expect this to be named legend.key.background similar to other components.